# Looking for a simple stock portfolio app (macOS)

Tags: ios, macos

While Apple introduced a rudimentary stock price application in macOS recently, it is not relly functionally adequate for even the most basic requirements.

I did not, however, find an app with the following feature set on the App Store yet, and would like to ask for suggestions:

- Relatively simple, lightweight and inexpensive
- Must offer at least
  two lists of stocks, so users can separate a "portfolio" from a
  "watchlist"
- Must support notes and price markers (i.e. have a way to
  remember what price a stock was bought at and a way to mark an
  arbitrary price with a user-defined note)#
- Must support alerts when
  the price hits user-defined values
- Should support alerts when the
  price meets other criteria, such as "alert me when the price drops
  more than 5% in one month"
- Should support ISINs and WKNs to identify stocks

I would also be willing to consider mobile apps for ipadOS, but am hesitant to put such data in a cloud somewhere, so web-based solutions are not interesting for me (although it may be a good idea to list them for the benefit of other readers). In case it is relevant, I am from central Europe and so an app focused solely on US exchanges would not be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a rather sophisticated open source tool called "[Portfolio Performance](https://www.portfolio-performance.info/en/)". "PP" has been active and well-maintained for several years and has an active community of both users and developers. The only drawbacks seem to be that it has a bit of a learning curve, and that alerts can only be triggered on fixed amounts, not percentages. Apart from that, it fulfills all criteria defined in the question and can analyze quite complex portfolios.